# Persistent vertical blue line (Macbook pro 13 mid 2010)

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Can anyone help me understand what this is? The line is persistent and i'm not sure it's because of a faulty LCD or something else. Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That looks very much like a column of stuck pixels to me. Similar happened on one of my devices recently.

Only fix is to replace the screen.

Comment: Could also be a faulty cable or GPU, but I'd guess it's the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's the LVDS cable.  You'll need to take it in for service.